# Port forwarding between 2 routers and wrong IP at the end

Tags: ip, port, forwarding

So here is the situation:

- I have adsl modem connected to 1st router "A" - local IP 192.168.2.1
- I forward SSH port to 2nd router "B" - IP 192.168.1.1
- On router "B" I forward SSH port to machine - 192.168.1.100

It works, I can login to my SSH server remotely, but the issue is when I check SSH logs, all the login attempts IP addresses are local. For example:

```
Mar 28 13:09:12 myserver sshd[14956]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 192.168.2.1 port 44341 ssh2
```

Same thing happens when I forward http ports.

How to fix it? I need to known proper IP addresses in order to restrict ssh access.

1st router is Mikrotik, 2nd CISCO, and I use CentOS on server.

```
       +-----------+    +-----------+    +-------------+
 ASDL  | Router A  |    | Router B  |    | SSH Server  |
------>| Miktrotik |--->|   Cisco   |--->|   CentOS    |
 modem |192.168.2.1|    |192.168.1.1|    |192.168.1.100|
       +-----------+    +-----------+    +-------------+
```

Comment: If you included the actual forwarding rule from the Mikrotik in your question, it may be possible to provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: If the schematics of the network are accurate, then there is nothing in the structure of the network, which makes it impossible to preserve the client IP. The schematics would be a little clearer, if the IP of each router was clearly attached to the specific interface either on the inside or the outside. It is possible to have the same IP on both sides, but that's not the typical configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that because you are using NAT. You should put the filtering on the first router.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have some links where I can read about filtering?

Comment: While your question is offtopic, a quick google search will give you a huge number of results. Here is a guide from Mikrotik site on filtering with Mikrotik routers: http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Routing/Routing_filters .

Answer (score 2):

Whether this is possible or not depends on how the network setup looks. If the original client IP is preserved, return packets from the server will follow the default route onto the Internet. However they must be routed through router "B" and then through router "A" in order for those routers to revert the changes they made to the server IP address on the packets going into your network.

If the default route from the server to the Internet does take the packets through those routers, then it is possible to do what you are asking, assuming both routers are capable of preserving the client IP as they are forwarding traffic.

Since the server sees the IP of router "A", it looks like router "B" is already configured to preserve the client IP. Thus you just need to reconfigure router "A" to preserve the client IP, as it is forwarding the packets.

I don't know Mikrotik, so I cannot tell you how to configure router "A", just that it is that part you are missing.